# Enable Team site for a publishing site?

Tags: feature

How to enable team site for an existing publishing site?

Answer (score 5):

To add the team site components to a publishing site you should enable the "Team Collaboration Lists" feature.

[image]

Comment: @djeed: I went to the site setting of the site collection and "Team collaboration lists" is not listed

Comment: @Foo Do not go to "Site collection features". Go to "Manage site features" under the "Site Actions" header on the Site Settings page. This feature is not scoped for a site collection. http://msadvisorwl.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/045329b25eca0987e4c83f46c62c4d3a.png

Answer (score 0):

To turn on publishing for a site when publishing is already turned on for the site collection:

Site Actions > Site Settings > Manage site features

Activate: SharePoint Server Publishing